# NativeScript-vue Save Image from url

Tags: mobile, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I will like to save an image from a web URL to the device can anyone help?
I've tried using the imageSource module but it only speaks of images from local device

Comment: You can write an API to return your image as base64string in json and have your app to persist the data using application settings

Comment: Do you want to show that image in your component html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const imageSourceModule = require("tns-core-modules/image-source");
const fileSystemModule = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");



imageSourceModule.fromUrl(webURL).then((res) => {
    const folderDest = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp();
    const pathDest = fileSystemModule.path.join(folderDest.path, "test.png");
    const saved = res.saveToFile(pathDest, "png");
if (saved) { 
    console.log("Image saved successfully!");
    this.image =  imageSourceModule.fromFile(pathDest);

}
```

thanks to @Narendra Mongiya for the first answer which help get the image from url

Comment: Good to know that @Nsagha ! If you mark that as accepted answer and upvote, it may be helpful to others. Happy Coding !!

Comment: Ok will do that

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should be (I am assuming that your webURL returns jpg/png etc)

```
const imageSource = require('image-source');
imageSource.fromUrl(webURL).then((res: any) => {
                           this.imageUrl = res;
        }).catch(err => {
            this.imageUrl = this.getIconSource('default_image');
        });
```

and in html file

```
<Image [src]="imageUrl" loadMode="async"></Image>
```

and for the default images if URL return blank

```
public getIconSource(icon: string): string {
        return isAndroid ? `res://${icon}` : 'res://images/' + icon;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gets the image but I do not know where or if the image is saving to the device please clarify me on this part thanks once more